# Spring Security Issues - Web app starts without error but behaves erratically

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

Something is configured incorrectly with my Spring Security xwl and I'd like help figuring out what it is. Upon opening the website, one is allowed to visit pages /*, as expected. Trying to access ones like /user/* redirect to /login, as expected. However, incorrect login information allows for success and the user is directed to the page contents of /user/files. An odd thing is that the url remains /login. Additionally, any attempt to go to another /user/* page result in a redirect to the login page.

But yes, I cannot figure out the problem for the life of me, any help is appreciated. I'm going to include all of the relevant bits of my web app in case it's something other than my spring-security.xml file.

Here's the relevant part of my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And my spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<bean id="authenticator" class="com.company.web.security.CompanyUserDetailsService" />

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/error/403"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        default-target-url="/user/files"
        always-use-default-target='false'/>
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </security:session-management>
    <security:remember-me />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticator" />
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

As you can tell, I've written a User Details Service which queries the database and returns a User object.

```
public class CompanyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

private TitanController titan = TitanController.getInstance();

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) 
        throws UsernameNotFoundException{
    return new CompanyUserDetails(this.titan.getUserFromEmail(username));
}

}
```

Here's the DAO logic for returning a User:

```
UserDetails userDetails;
Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
if (dbUser != null){
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    userDetails = new User(dbUser.getEmail(), dbUser.getPassword(), authorities);
} else {
    userDetails = new User(null, null, authorities);
}
return userDetails;
```

The login page controller is quite simple:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginController {  

TitanController titan = TitanController.getInstance();

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLogin(Model model) {
    return "login";
}
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postLogin(){
    return "files";
}
}
```

And finally, here's the login.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  th:include="components/layout :: loggedout">
<div th:fragment="content">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
    <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">               
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">log in</h2>
            </legend>
            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error text-center">    
                Invalid username or password.
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success text-center"> 
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
            <label for="username" class="sr-only">email address</label>
            <input name="username" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email address" required="true" autofocus="true" />
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required="true" />
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> remember me </input>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">log in</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-2"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, please ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Could you try changing springSecurityFilterChain in your web.xml from /user/* to /*

Comment: Also in the login form use th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" and the inputs to j_username and j_password

Comment: Ditch your `LoginController` Spring Security handles that for you. You only protected `/user/*` everything else is unprotected. A `*` means a single level whereas `**` means 0 or more. So I would suspect those two things not helping you in securing your application. Finally your dao is also wrong, if no user is found it should return NULL as defined by the contract, however you are returning a user.

Comment: @M.Deinum I double checked on the contract - it should never return null. However, it should throw a UserNotFoundException, yet another problem with my setup. Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I was pointed in the correct direction by the comments - it was actually two different problems at the same time.

The post action was being handled by my login controller, not spring security. So, I deleted the post method. Additionally, the post was not being called correctly or passed the correct parameters - so I changed the action to th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" and the inputs to j_username and j_password. Thanks @PatrickLC and @M.Deinum.